# AutoMapper - how to use type converter on a single property

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to use AutoMapper with a single property?
I would like to convert a string value of comma delimited values to a list of values separated by a line feed on the UI.

The current custom converters only seem to work at the class level, and because the dest and source types are both string I can't create a single map based on .

How would I apply the custom converter on a single property?  Or should the custom resolver be used instead?

Comment: If you are using WPF do this in with a ValueConverter. In any case in order to me is better to do this in the view, not in the dto mapper ( but is an opinion )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use a custom resolver or map the property by calling your convert logic in a MapFrom lambda:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>().ForMember(dto => dto.DestPrp,
                                                        e => e.MapFrom(o => ConvertTo(o.SourceProp)))
```

Comment: ConvertTo() - is this an AutoMapper method or one of my own?

Comment: Your own tailored specifically for the given property conversion.

Comment: Ok, I could actually just do: o=>o.MyProperty.Replace(",",Environment.NewLine);

Comment: So why does AutoMapper take an `Expression<Func<>>` if it actually CALLS the code? Why not take a `Func<>` instead?